# Transforming a logical condition with AND and OR

Tags: algorithm, conditional-statements

I have a complex condition, with ANDs and ORs, for example :
`(c1 OR c2) AND (c3 OR c4 OR c5)`

This is equivalent to :

`(c1 AND c3) OR (c1 AND c4) OR (c1 AND c5) OR (c2 AND c3) OR (c2 AND c4) OR (c2 AND c5)`

This condition can be then exploded in a list of conditions that contains only AND :

```
c1 AND c3
c1 AND c4
c1 AND c5
c2 AND c3
c2 AND c4
c2 AND c5
```

Is this transformation always possible ? and what algorithm could do it ?

Conditions are stored in memory as trees, eg :

```
    OR
   /  \
  AND c1
 / ! \
c2 c3 c4
```

I think we should try to "move" the OR upwards the tree, by using distributivity :

`(a OR b) AND c = (a AND c) OR (b AND c)`.

Is that a good approach ?

Comment: This maybe solved only storing in list NOT ONLY pairs, but also 1 or 3,4 etc. numbers combined via AND. Example condition c1 AND c2 AND c3. can't be simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (or [Conjunctive one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)). But they both uses not only `AND` and `OR` but `NOT` too.

**Note**: if we are restricted with `OR`s and `AND`s only (and cannot use any other boolean function), then we even can't express any boolean function because of [Post's functional completeness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_functional_completeness_theorem) (`AND` and `OR` are both truth-preserving and don't form a basis). Therefore *maybe* there is a formula, that can't be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

`(a or b) and c` is logically equivalent to `(a and c) or (b and c)`. However, in languages that support short-circuiting boolean expressions, I would probably end up writing that as `c and (a or b)`, on the grounds that it's unnecessary to evaluate `(a or b)` if `c` is false.

This is especially true if either `a` or `b` are expensive function calls rather than just variable references.